# Electric potential inside shell

Tags: electrostatics

Suppose we have a hollow neutral shell  and $q$ charge at $r$ from its center now we take a point a someplace other than center then will electric potential change? I don't think because electric field inside shell is zero so we have constant potential

Comment: r<R(radius of shell)???

Comment: Imagine a hollow metallic sphere which is not charged . Now we have a point charge outside of sphere at distance r from centre of sphere we have potential say V at center of sphere , now we take another point inside shell which is not its center , Will potential change value here?

Comment: You cannot calculate potential like that if conductor is present because the charge will induce some charge on the conductor.
Try to use method of images.http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node64.html

Comment: Actually method of images is used to calculate the potential outside the shell.The potential inside the shell will be constant since electric field is zero inside.

Answer (score 1):

For any (perfect) conducting shell the electric or magnetic fields will induce some charges to move through the shell such that they cancel the fields inside. This is called a 'Faraday's cage'.

So it doesn't matter what field's or currents you apply outside of the shell, the fields inside will always cancel.

Answer (score 1):

> Imagine a hollow metallic sphere which is not charged . Now we have a
>   point charge outside of sphere at distance r from centre of sphere we
>   have potential say V at center of sphere , now we take another point
>   inside shell which is not its center , Will potential change value
>   here?

1. Since there is no charge inside, the potential inside satisfies
   [Laplace's equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaplacesEquation.html), i.e., *the potential inside can have no local
   maxima or minima.*
2. Since the sphere is a conductor, *it is an [equipotential surface](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22776/in-electrostatics-why-the-conductor-is-an-equipotential-surface)*.

It follows that the potential inside is constant.

Comment: So what is paul talking about on mirror charge method

Comment: @Sigma, as Paul correctly points out, the method of images gives the potential outside the sphere, not inside (the region where the image charge is).